# Comments are not nesting in Rails using ancestry gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I am using the ancestry gem to nest comments, and everything works, replying, editing, creating, deleting. But for some reason the comments them selves will not nest under the comment you are replying to - instead it ends up at the end of the list of comments.

**code**

**Note:** Tasks has many categories where as category belongs to task

**Category new method**

```
  def new
    @task = Task.find(params[:task_id])
    @task.comments.new(:parent_id => params[:parent_id])
  end
```

**Comments Helper**

```
module CommentsHelper
  def nested_comments(comments)
    comments.map do |comment, sub_comments|
      render(comment) + content_tag(:div, nested_comments(sub_comments), :class => 'nested_comments')
    end.join.html_safe
  end
end
```

**Comments form**

```
<%= form_for ([@task, @task.comments.build]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :comment %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :parent_id%>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

When I reply to or post a new comment this is what I get in the source:

```
<div class="comment_23">

    <p>I am a comment</p>
    <div class="comment Info">
        Written by: Adam | 
        You can: <a href="/tasks/7/comments/new?parent_id=23">Reply To Comment</a> or
        <a href="/tasks/1/comments/23/edit">Edit Comment</a>  |
        <a href="/tasks/1/comments/23" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete Comment</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="nested_comments"></div><div class="comment_24">

    <p>I am another comment</p>
    <div class="comment Info">
        Written by: Adam | 
        You can: <a href="/tasks/7/comments/new?parent_id=24">Reply To Comment</a> or
        <a href="/tasks/1/comments/24/edit">Edit Comment</a>  |
        <a href="/tasks/1/comments/24" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete Comment</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="nested_comments"></div><div class="comment_25">

    <p>I am a reply to the first comment</p>
    <div class="comment Info">
        Written by: Adam | 
        You can: <a href="/tasks/7/comments/new?parent_id=25">Reply To Comment</a> or
        <a href="/tasks/1/comments/25/edit">Edit Comment</a>  |
        <a href="/tasks/1/comments/25" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete Comment</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="nested_comments"></div>
```

Why are there empty nested_comments divs? and I am a test is a reply to I am a comment, so why is it not with in the nested comments div?

Comment: I was wondering, have you been able to find the source of the bug? I am in the same problem myself.